# SQL Server 2008 error - Incorrect syntax near '%'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 102). The step failed

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL query that fails with the above error when used in a SQL job designed to email the query results.  The syntax is fine when running a normal query.

I see that other people have had this issue when using non-standard characters in server names, but my issue is with the % signs in my query I think and the other solutions don't work for me :

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'SQL-Server',
@recipients = 'XXXXX',
@subject = 'Missing Essence File Check',
@query = N'SELECT *   FROM ([omnibus].[dbo].[OmniBus_CLP_Clips] CLP 
inner join [omnibus].[dbo].[OmniBus_CLD_ClipDetails] CLD on CLP.FLE_ID = CLD.FLE_ID) 
inner join [omnibus].[dbo].[OmniBus_FLE_Files] fle on clp.FLE_ID = fle.fle_id
where CLD_user_data  like '%.mov%'
and CLD_user_data  not like '%.m2v%'
and CLD_user_data  not like '%.wav%'
and fle.FLE_file_deleted = 0;',
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
@query_attachment_filename = 'Missing Essence File Check.txt'
```

Can anyone advise on how to overcome this error?

Thanks,

Rob

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting.

Comment: You need to escape your single quotes by doubling them.   Any good dynamic sql tutorial should demonstrate this.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this line.

```
where CLD_user_data  like '''%.mov%'''
and CLD_user_data  not like '''%.m2v%'''
and CLD_user_data  not like '''%.wav%'''
```

Comment: This worked, but you've put 3 single quotes around each file extension and it should actually be two.